# Does getpwnam respect /etc/nsswitch.conf?

Tags: linux, unix, authentication, system-calls, getpwnam

Does getpwnam respect /etc/nsswitch.conf?

The manpage  for `getpwnam` states

> The getpwnam() function returns a pointer to a structure containing the broken-out
>   fields of  the  record
>   in  the  password  database  (e.g.,  the local password file /etc/passwd, NIS, and 
>   LDAP) that matches the
>         username name.

This leads me to believe that it should respect /etc/nsswitch.conf, iterating over whatever entries are listed for the `passwd` line (... but I have a bug report indicating that it's not behaving that way).

Edit: I found a [3c manpage](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-comment/man.cgi?section=3C&topic=getpwnam) that indicates that it does respect it, so now the question is under which operating systems is it supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does respect /etc/nsswitch.conf under every operating system which is POSIX conform.

Answer (score 2):

Although it will normally respect `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (or whatever passwd-database selection mechanism the OS supports), on some systems this does not work if the application was statically linked.  This is because the appropriate database library is dynamically loaded into the program.

Comment: The static linking is a good point, although not applicable in my situation.